# How to specify comparator for following map of map

Tags: java

How to specify comparator for following map of map

```
ConcurrentSkipListMap<byte[], ConcurrentSkipListMap<byte[], ConcurrentSkipListMap<byte[], Object>>> myIndex;
```

Will the following declaration correct

```
myIndex = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<byte[], ConcurrentSkipListMap<byte[], ConcurrentSkipListMap<byte[], Object>>>(new MyCustomComparator)
```

Will this comparator be applicable to inner ConcurrentSkipListMap

Comment: create a new `Comparator`

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your data structure. How about a specific class for your `Map<Map<Maps`...? Those generics are far from being beautiful...

Answer (score 1):

No it wont be applicable to inner ConcurrentSkipListMap. You have to pass it to the constructor of the inner ConcurrentSkipListMap(), when you create a instance of the inner map.

Comment: How do you know? We haven't seem the definition of the named class - it might be OK, who knows...